# How to access details one by one from mysql using First Next Previous Last button with ajax?

Tags: php, javascript, mysql, ajax

I have made a question database with id . Now i am using ajax to access the mysql database question one by one  using First Next Previous Last button. How to do it. Here is my code.

## index.php

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">
var str;
function showid(str)
{
if (str=="")
  {
  document.getElementById("txtHint").innerHTML="";
  return;
  }
if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
  {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
  xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
  }
else
  {// code for IE6, IE5
  xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
  }
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
  {
  if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
    {
    document.getElementById("txtHint").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;

    }
  }
xmlhttp.open("GET","request.php?q="+str,true);
xmlhttp.send();
}
</script>
</head>
<body onLoad="showid(1)">

<br />
<div id="txtHint">Requested Data
</div>
<br />

<input type="button" value="Last" name="First" onClick="showid(1)"  />
<input type="button" value="Previous" name="Previous" onClick="showid(2)"  />
<input type="button" value=Next name="Next" onClick="showid(3)"  />
<input type="button" value="First" name="Last" id="Last" onClick="showid(4)"  />


</body>
</html>
```

## requesting page

```
<?php
$q=$_GET["q"];

$con = mysql_connect("localhost", "root", "");
if (!$con)
  {
  die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
  }

mysql_select_db("dbase", $con);

$sql="SELECT * FROM table WHERE id = '".$q."'";

$result = mysql_query($sql);

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
  {
  $id=$row['id'];
  }
mysql_close($con);



?>
```

Comment: <input type="button" value="|<" name="First" onClick="showQuestion(1)" /> <input type="button" value="<" name="Previous" onClick="showQuestion(2)" /> <input type="button" value=">" name="Next" onClick="showQuestion(3)" /> <input type="button" value=">|" name="Last" id="Last" onClick="showQuestion(4)" /> Here i want to pass the value in showQuestion function dynamically for first next prev last button

Comment: what is the problem: there are errors or response is incorrect?

Comment: Thanks. there are no errors on response ..but i want to pass the value dynamically to the showQuestion() function  based on next & previous buttons logic.

Comment: NOTICE: You don't need a while loop in your `question.php` file 'cuz I guess there's only ONE record which match the `ID`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using javascript to set the current question number and work from there.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var str;
var current_question = 1;
function showQuestion(_direction)
{
if(_direction == 'prev') current_question--;
else if(_direction == 'next') current_question++;
else if(_direction == 'first') current_question = 1;
else if(_direction == 'last') current_question = ?; // use php to set this when producing page
//...
xmlhttp.open("GET","question.php?q="+current_question,true);
xmlhttp.send();
```

then change your inputs like so

```
<input type="button" value="|<" name="First" onClick="showQuestion('first')"  />
<input type="button" value="<" name="Previous" onClick="showQuestion('prev')"  />
<input type="button" value=">" name="Next" onClick="showQuestion('next')"  />
<input type="button" value=">|" name="Last" id="Last" onClick="showQuestion('last')"  />
```

Comment: @Mahfuz No problem, if this solved your question you can mark my answer as complete or upvote it